# How can I allow my function to accepts two different objects in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, oop

I have a function which takes one argument. I wanted my function to accept two object types. How can I do it? Here is the example below:

```
func accept(user: Customer) {
  ...
}
```

It should accept Customer and Employee object reference.

```
accept(objRefCustomer)
accept(objRefEmployee)
```

Please help me in this case.

Comment: why cant you try using func accept(user: NSObject)

Comment: but how can use their properties?

Comment: then you can have to inherit the classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Alternative to super-classing: use protocols

You needn't necessarily use a superclass for this case (if `Customer` and `Employee` are struct value types; superclass option is not possible), but can rather use the more generic approach of protocols.

Define a protocol `Users` which blueprints properties and methods for your `Customer` and `Employee` instances (if we let `Customer` and `Employee` conform to `Users`, then we promise that instances of these two structures will have accessible the blueprinted properties and methods):

```
protocol Users {
    var name: String { get }
    func printTypeOfUser()
}
```

Define the `Customer` and `Employee` structures, and their conformance to the protocol `Users`:

```
struct Customer : Users {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }

    func printTypeOfUser() {
        print("Is a Customer!")
    }
}

struct Employee : Users {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    init(name: String, id: Int) { self.name = name; self.id = id }
    
    func printTypeOfUser() {
        print("Is an Employee!")
    }
}
```

Now you can define a generic function where its generic, say `T`, is type constrained to types conforming to the protocol `Users`, which in this case is equivalent to the `Customer` or `Employee` types

```
func accept<T: Users>(user: T) {
    print("Name of user: \(user.name) [\(user.dynamicType)]")
    user.printTypeOfUser()
    
    // do something additional employee-specific if user is an employee?
    if let employee = user as? Employee {
        print("User is an employee with id: \(employee.id)")
    }
}
```

Example usage of this function for `Employee` as well as `Customer` instances:

```
let employee = Employee(name: "John", id: 1)
let customer = Customer(name: "Sarah")

accept(employee) /* Name of user: John [Employee] 
                    Is an Employee!
                    User is an employee with id: 1 */

accept(customer) /* Name of user: Sarah [Customer]
                    Is a Customer!                 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I need to stick to class type

Comment: @coolly the above is just as valid for classes as for structs (just replace `struct` with `class` in the definitions of `Customer` and `Employee` above). For classes, you do indeed have the alternative of introducing a superclass; if this superclass is never explicitly used as a type itself (i.e., no superclass objects), however, then protocols might be a more Swifty solution.

Comment: name is not required in both the classes. I tried to make it optional but it throws me an error. I tried var optional name:String in protocol.

Comment: @coolly I think you would benefit greatly by reading the [Swift Language Guide - The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html), making sure you understand the very important concepts of **optionals** and **protocols** in Swift. After grasping the basics of these subjects, feel free to update this question with more details regarding your specific implementation. I will suspect, however, that you will possibly be able to solve these issues yourself once you've thoroughly covered the fundamental concepts of Swift.

Comment: may be you have understood my above comment in a different way, it was specific to optional of a property but not property optional. Anyhow, I was able to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of changing your Class structure and code base, you can use `AnyObject`. It will also be easier for you if, for example, in future you have to make this function accept parameters of class `WaterMelon`. Making all these classes inherit from a common parent class would be unnecessary overhead, not to mention hectic.

[AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_AnyObject_Protocol/index.html) is swift equivalent of objective c `id`. AnyObject is a protocol that can represent an instance of any class type.

It also has a more general counterpart, `Any`, which can represent any type at all (including `structs` and `enums`).

Following code will accept any class type parameter you pass:

```
func accept(sender : AnyObject) { //Or AnyObject? if you want to handle nil as well
      ...
    }
```

To access properties of the classes you pass as `AnyObject`, you can use [type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

For example below code will check sender type and typecast it for you:

```
if let customerRef = sender as? Customer {
    // ...
    // Sender is of customer class type. Use it with customerRef that we created
    let customerName = customerRef.dynamicType.sampleNameProperty //Access a property of class Customer
    customerRef.funcOfCustomerClass() //Call a method of class Customer
}
else{
 //Sender is not of customer class type. 
//Then it must be Employee??? Handle cases for employee here.
}
```

Comment: how can i access sender properties?

Comment: you mean like this sender.propertyName as Customer ?

Comment: it throws me compilation error if I am trying to access its property "Value of type has no member" @nsnoob

Comment: Note that `accept(...)` as above will allow being called with _any kind of class instance_, not just the intended instances of `Customer`/`Employee` class. Hence, the statement _"then it must be Employee"_ in the `else` clause above is not true, as it might as well be any class instance "wrapped" by the `AnyObject` type. Imho, `AnyObject` has its uses (esp. when working with obj-c/cocoa), but this is not one of them, as `accept(...)` function as above is way more general/generic than it need to be: as more "encapsulating" alternatives exists, I believe the solution as above should be avoided.

Comment: but anyhow customer.propertyName is not able to accept during app build.

Comment: @dfri I agree and that's why I made the comment about it being Employee a question with three question marks. I am relying on OP here that he will only send either Customer or Employee as parameters. If he wants to send more types, he will have to handle their cases as well. Here our assumption is that there are going to be either Customers or Employees. Anyways, You might be right as my knowledge of swift is limited as I primarily work in Obj-c

Comment: @coolly that's strange [It should work with instance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html). Did you try accessing it after removing `dynamicType`?

Comment: It would be helpful to debug this if you added classes customer and employee here.

Comment: yes I tried it in both ways with and without dynamicType. It didn't worked. Ended up going with protocol. But got stuck there like how to declare an optional property, not this '?' by the way. Property itself an optional.

Answer (score 3):

create a `protocol`, and use it as argument type. protocol can be also empty, it will work anyway. Works with `struct` and `class` as well;

ex:

```
protocol SomeFakeProtocol {}
class SomeClass: SomeFakeProtocol { //code here }
struct SomeStruct: SomeFakeProtocol { //code here }

func someFunction(arg: SomeFakeProtocol) { //code here }
```

Benefits - you can allow to use only types you want to. And, sure, you can do things like this:

```
extension String: SomeFakeProtocol {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a super class called `People` of `Cutomer` and `Employee`.

Then set `user` as type of `People`:

```
func accept(user: People) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: just because I want to pass different objects for the same function do I need to make a super class?

Comment: Cast them to `Customer` or `Employee`, then you can access them.

Comment: you mean like this sender.propertyName as Customer

Comment: first I have to check whether passed value was customer or employee right?

Comment: Yes, then you just cast this.

Comment: @coolly Just because you want to pass different objects to the same function _does not mean you necessarily need to introduce a super class_, another alternative is [using protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37000368/4573247).

Comment: well, ya that's what first comment on this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a super class, you can just pass an object of type AnyObject and in your function check the type of the object passed:

```
func accept(user: AnyObject) {
    if let usr = user as? Person {
        ...
    }
}
```

But if you have many types you want to pass you may want to make a protocol or a super class.

Comment: but if I access usr property it throws me an error while building the project

Comment: This is the code I took from the testing playground and it works, no errors: class 

Person {
    var name:String = ""
    var time:NSDate?
}

func accept(user: AnyObject) {
    if let usr = user as? Person {
        print(usr.name)
    }
}

Comment: But the best way to achieve what you want is to use protocols, like others mentioned above :-).